# Install jdk 8 without admin privileges

Tags: install, java, administrator

Is there a way to install or run jdk 8 without admin privileges? I would like to compile a java project I have that requires jdk 8 on a computer that has only jdk 6 installed. I am not an administrator on the computer.

Comment: did you check this out ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24204430

Comment: @Buscar웃 Just did [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html) and there is no mac version.

Comment: and this ?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jre.html#CHDGECEB

Comment: It says it can't be installed for a single user and needs administrator privileges.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) to view the contents of the JDK installer package. You can use it to extract the files to your user library folder `~/Library` instead of the system wide `/Library`.

The relevant subfolders in `Library` are `Internet Plug-Ins`, `Java`, and an alias in `PreferencePanes`.

See this screenshot for the path structure.

[image: Imgur]

Moving the files can be done manually or by modifying the installer package.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need admin rights to install that where it would be able to be used in the way you need it to be.